# How to display data from mysql using php to html page

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hi I'm learning php and mysql and creating simple user system. Now I wan't to display user data from mysql to the page using PHP. But I'm struggling with that because I can't get data from databasa even though user correctly sign in. I don't know what is wrong with the code, can't find problem and I was trying difference ways to grab data and display but nothing is working and always variable with data is empty.

login-process.php

```
<?php 

include('connection.php');


$error = array();

$email = $_POST['email'];

if(empty($email)){
    $error[] = 'Email can not be empty!';
}

$password = $_POST['password'];

if(empty($password)){
    $error[] = 'Password can not be empty!';
}

if(empty($error)){

    // query

    $query = "SELECT userID, firstName, lastName, email, password, profileImage FROM user WHERE email=?";
    $q = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    mysqli_stmt_prepare($q, $query);

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($q, 's', $email);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($q);

    // store result

    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($q);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    if(!empty($row)){
        // checking password
        // unhasing password
        if(password_verify($password, $row['password'])){
            header('location: user-profile.php');
            exit();
        } else {
            echo "You are not a member";
        }
    }


}


// get user info
function get_user_info($con, $userID){
    $query = "SELECT firstName, lastName, email, profileImage FROM user WHERE userID=?";
    $q = mysqli_stmt_init($con);

    mysqli_stmt_prepare($q, $query);

    // bind the statement
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($q, 'i', $userID);

    // execute sql statement
    mysqli_stmt_execute($q);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($q);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    return empty($row) ? false : $row;
}
```

user-profile.php

```
<?php

session_start();
include ('header.php');

$user = array();


if(isset($_SESSION['userID'])){
    require ('mysqli_connect.php');
    $user = get_user_info($con, $_SESSION['userID']);
}

?>

<section id="main-site">
    <div class="container py-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 offset-4 shadow py-4">
                <div class="upload-profile-image d-flex justify-content-center pb-5">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <img class="img rounded-circle" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" src="<?php echo isset($user['profileImage']) ? $user['profileImage'] : './assets/profile/beard.png'; ?>" alt="">
                        <h4 class="py-3">
                            <?php
                            if(isset($user['firstName'])){
                                printf('%s %s', $user['firstName'], $user['lastName'] );
                            }
                            ?>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="user-info px-3">
                    <ul class="font-ubuntu navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-link"><b>First Name: </b><span><?php echo isset($user['firstName']) ? $user['firstName'] : ''; ?></span></li>
                        <li class="nav-link"><b>Last Name: </b><span><?php echo isset($user['lastName']) ? $user['lastName'] : ''; ?></span></li>
                        <li class="nav-link"><b>Email: </b><span><?php echo isset($user['email']) ? $user['email'] : ''; ?></span></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<?php
include "footer.php";
?>
```

login.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include ('header.php');
    include('login-process.php');
?>
<?php
    $user = array();
    require ('connection.php');
    

    if(isset($_SESSION['userID'])){
        $user = get_user_info($conn, $_SESSION['userID']);
    }

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        require ('login-process.php');
    }
?>
    <section id="register">
        <nav class="navbar nav">
            <a href="register.php"><img src="./image/logo.png" width="150px" height="150px" alt=""></a>
        </nav>
        <div class="row ml-5 m-0">
            <div class="col-lg-4 offset-lg-1">
                <div class="text-center pb-5">
                    <h1 class="login-title text-white">Sign in.</h1>
                    <p class="p-1 m-0 font-poppins text-white-50">Welcome back! Please enter your details.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="upload-profile-image d-flex justify-content-center pb-5">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <img class="camera-icon" src="./image/camera.png" alt="camera">
                        </div>
                        <img src=<?php echo isset($user['profileImage']) ? $user['profileImage']: "./assets/profile-picture/avatar.jpg"; ?> style="width: 200px; height: 200px" class="img rounded-circle" alt="profile">
                        <small class="form-text text-white-50">Choose Image</small>
                        <input type="file" form="reg-form" class="form-control-file" name="profileUpload" id="upload-profile">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <form action="login.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="reg-form">
                        <div class="form-row my-4">
                            <div class="col">
                                <input type="email" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email'])) echo $_POST['email'];  ?>" required name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email*">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-row my-4">
                            <div class="col">
                                <input type="password" required name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password*">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <small id="login-error" class="text-danger">hi</small>
                        <div class="form-inline">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="agreement" class="form-check-input">
                            <label for="agreement" class="form-check-label pr-3 font-poppins text-white-50">Remember for 30 days</label>
                            <a href="#">Forgot password</a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="submit-btn text-center my-5">
                            <button type="submit" onclick="confirmPassword(event)" class="btn btn-dark  rounded-pill text-white px-5 py-3">Create account</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


<?php
    include ('footer.php');
?>
```

register-process.php

```
<?php

include ('connection.php');

//data from the form
$firstName = $_POST['first-name'];
$lastName = $_POST['last-name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$files = $_FILES['profileUpload'];
$profileImage = upload_profile("./assets/profile-picture", $files);


//sending data from input to the database
$sql = "INSERT INTO user VALUES (DEFAULT , '$firstName', '$lastName', '$email', '$password', '$profileImage', NOW())";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['userID'] = mysqli_insert_id($con);


    header('location:login.php');
    exit();

} else {
    echo "ERROR";
    echo  mysqli_error($conn);

}

//image

function upload_profile($path, $file){
    $targetDir = $path;
    $default = "avatar.jpg";

    $filename = basename($file['name']);
    $targetFilePath = $targetDir.$filename;
    $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if(!empty($filename)){
        // file format
        $allowType = array('jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'jpeg');
        if(in_array($fileType, $allowType)){
            // send file to the folder
            if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $targetFilePath)){
                return $targetFilePath;
            };
        }
    }

    //if user does not load picture return the default one

    return $path .$default;

}
```

I would like to ask for code example how to display data from database into website when I have ID

Comment: Looks like `$_SESSION['userID']` is never set

Comment: in the login process you do not set the session variable

Comment: (a) If $_SESSION['userID'] is say empty, please redirect to login page. (b) upon successful login, please set $_SESSION['userID'] to be equal to userID. (c) initialize the $_SESSION['userID'] to be say empty if it has not been set - just use isset to check

Comment: so how can I grab userID when user log in,  because while log in is correctly checking email and password but then when I check value it is empty

Comment: The userID is inside the userID column of your user db table. You get it thru your select statement (see ?)

Comment: yes but I alreaady set the $_session['userID'] in a register-process.php file (I edit post) but still the value are empty even though user is correctly sign in i don't understand...

Comment: can u tell me how should look example code for display data from mysql into html website using php when we have id and we wanna grab others column set to this id?

Comment: You're setting `$_SESSION['userID']` when a user _registers_, but _not_ when a user _logs in_? Set it again before you redirect to `user-profile.php`

Comment: @brombeer exactly!!! omgg thank you so much, it's working!!

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting `$_SESSION['userId']` when a user logs in successfully, so the part

```
if(isset($_SESSION['userID'])){
    $user = get_user_info($conn, $_SESSION['userID']);
}
```

will not trigger and `$user` will not be set.

Change

```
if(password_verify($password, $row['password'])){
    header('location: user-profile.php');
    exit();
} else {
    echo "You are not a member";
}
```

to

```
if(password_verify($password, $row['password'])){
    $_SESSION['userId'] = $row['userId']
    header('location: user-profile.php');
    exit();
} else {
    echo "You are not a member";
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what have I done after your clue, thank you so much! :)

Answer (score -1):

You haven't set the value for

```
$_SESSION['userID']
```

use this

```
session_start();
$user_id = $_SESSION['userID'];
```

hope it will solve your problem

Comment: "_hope it will solve your problem_" It won't. What is `$user_id`? `$_SESSION['userID']` will _not_ be set when using this code